# Nmap wont scan with -oN or -oG

Tags: nmap

I'm trying to use nmap for port scanning some instances and I would like to have it give me some better looking output.  I would like to use the `-oG` or `-oN` options, however neither seem to work and using gives me the following output:

```
user@hostname:~$ nmap -oG 1.2.3.4

Starting Nmap 7.30 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-14 10:36 PDT
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.03 seconds


user@hostname:~$ nmap -oN 1.2.3.4

Starting Nmap 7.30 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-14 10:36 PDT
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

How do I get it to scan my instance with this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output file options (`-oN`, `-oG`, `-oX`, and `-oA`) all take a filename argument. Your commands are saying, "Generate grepable output and save it to the file called `1.2.3.4`." Then Nmap looks at the rest of the line and sees no target specifications (since it assumed `1.2.3.4` was a filename and not an IP address. This command would work instead: `nmap -oG myscan.gnmap 1.2.3.4`